# JS change image of many HTML elements and line-through their text

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement, text, getelementbyid

i think is a pretty simple JS script but for some reason i can't get my head around my problem. All i am trying to do is: i have a list of items and before them i have an image, an empty checkbox in my case. Now, if i click on that empty box, then another image replaces the old one (a ticked box) and the item is crossed over (line-through). If the item is already crossed over and having the ticked image, and click back on the image again, i want it to set both image and text decoration into their initial condition as before. 
So far what i 've done:

```
    <img id="tick_" onclick="myFunction()" src="image1.jpg" align="middle" /><strong id="cross">Item A</strong>
<img id="tick_" onclick="myFunction()" src="image1.jpg" align="middle" /><strong id="cross">Item B</strong>
<img id="tick_" onclick="myFunction()" src="image1.jpg" align="middle" /><strong id="cross">Item C</strong>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    if(document.getElementById("tick_").src == "image1.jpg"){
    document.getElementById("tick_").src = "image2.jpg";
    document.getElementById("cross").style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    }
       else {
    document.getElementById("tick_").src = "image1.jpg";
    document.getElementById("cross").style.textDecoration = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Results: it worked for the first item but not for the rest. Would a For case solve my problem? Could i use some help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: first of all `id` is meant to be unique for the whole application/site.

Comment: that's a very good point! ...Oh, i have to open my Uni books again...

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple elements with the same `id` tag. There should only ever be one element on your site with that same tag, the others should be different. Because JavaScript expects only one ID tag, it finds the first one and then stops. You could try something like this:

```js
function myFunction(element) {
  if(element.src == "image1.jpg"){
    element.src = "image2.jpg";
    element.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    } else {
    element.src = "image1.jpg";
    element.style.textDecoration = "none";
    }
};
```

```html
<img id="tick_" onclick="myFunction(this)" src="image1.jpg" align="middle" /><strong id="cross">Item A</strong>
<img id="tick_" onclick="myFunction(this)" src="image1.jpg" align="middle" /><strong id="cross">Item B</strong>
<img id="tick_" onclick="myFunction(this)" src="image1.jpg" align="middle" /><strong id="cross">Item C</strong>
```

Comment: Thank you HeroCC. But it partly works. I mean, i do get the onclick() work for the images but the function ignores the line-through style for my text. Only because the function is limited in the img element and only. How can i affect the <strong> text element too when i click on the image element?

Comment: Have i go any more suggestions about how to line-through the text of the clicked image? Please, any more ideas?

Comment: @BrainWash, you could try making everything into a div, and then put the image and text elements inside of it. Then use get the img tag inside that div and set it's source, and set the text tile (of the strong or entire div) to strikethrough.